# In Sinatra, what is the difference between production and development environment?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, development-environment, production-environment

I can't find an exhaustive answer.

What happens if I set "production"? I saw that view files are not read "on the fly" anymore, but are there other differences?

Comment: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#environments I think thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, only templates are affected by the env var.

You are free to implement every other application logic methods based on current env:

```
  if settings.production?
    # this will only run in production
  else
    # every other env
  end
```

You can also do something like this when need conditional configs:

```
configure :production, :development do
  enable :logging
end
```